# D3, is it possible to move a part of the path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

If I've a SVG path, with lots of lines and curves is it possible to select a part of the path and drag/move it around?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - events are attached to the path, not its nodes. But you might add (invisible) points to your plot that coincide with the nodes. Then you could attach events to the points that transform the path accordingly...?

Comment: It's possible but writing a complete svg editor is outside the scope of an answer here.